# Postgres Hot Standby and Long Running Queries On Slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

**Question**: Can you have long running queries (30s+) running while having WAL updates applied on the slave (the slave role is as a Reporting DB Server) in a Hot Standby mode? The way it's working now is, either you set the params below to kill long running queries so WAL updates can be applied, or delay the WAL updates indefinitely until no queries are running to apply them. Can we have both? Long running queries and WAL updates being applied at the same time?

**Case Implementation**: We are currently using Hot Standby mode to sync any changes from one master to one slave. The slave role is as a reporting db server with queries constantly and concurrently running (some in ms, some in seconds,
some in minutes.) It would be very rare to have a gap of no active queries running on the slave.

We have adjusted these two params to allow long queries on the hot standby:

```
max_standby_archive_delay = -1  # max delay before canceling queries
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1  # max delay before canceling queries
```

And looking at an archived mail question similar to ours in a postgres mailing list:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTinLg+bpzcjzdndsnGGNFC=D1OsVh+hKb85A-s=n@mail.gmail.com

I understand the concept of preventing WAL updates being applied to
slaves while queries are running. However, I thought with the use of MVCC,
an active query on the slave (long running, 30 seconds+) can run reading
from one version/snapshot, while the WAL update is being applied, so
subsequent queries will get the WAL updates when that WAL transaction is
committed. I haven't fully digested the MVCC model used in PostgreSQL yet
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-concurrency, so this is
just my assumption -- that even if a table is dropped / truncated during a
WAL update, the current running query should still work as it's using a
version/snapshot of the table(s) it's querying?

**Summary**: Is there anyway (even with a third party extension) we can sync slaves
from a master and have those updates from the master be applied to the
slave right away while letting queries of any execution time continue to
run till they complete on the standby/slave? If Hot Standby can't do that,
what would you recommend for this situation? Our scenario is that we are
hitting postgres with queries constantly and concurrently running (some in
ms, some in seconds, some in minutes,) leaving almost no time for a WAL
update to be applied. We have used Bucardo, but that wouldn't be a good
choice in this scenario, as we over 200+ tables that would need to be
synced, including views as well 40+ other databases aside from our main
database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate [14592436](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592436/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery)

Answer (score 30):

Thanks Guillaume for your answer, but luckily, starting in PostgreSQL 9.1, PostgreSQL has the `hot_standby_feedback` option (you set this on the standby server in postgresql.conf) which wont kill long running queries and will allow for WAL updates to the standby servers. Credit for this answer goes to three people on the PostgreSQL mail list (Raja/Albe/Scott) who helped me on this in that mailing thread. Hopefully this could be helpful to someone searching for this answer on stackoverflow. The email thread can be found here:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D274E3C1.1113E8%awilliams@dresourcesgroup.com

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hot-standby.html

Excerpt:

> Remedial possibilities exist if the number of standby-query cancellations is found to be unacceptable. The first option is to set the parameter `hot_standby_feedback`, which prevents `VACUUM` from removing recently-dead rows and so cleanup conflicts do not occur. If you do this, you should note that this will delay cleanup of dead rows on the primary, which may result in undesirable table bloat. However, the cleanup situation will be no worse than if the standby queries were running directly on the primary server, and you are still getting the benefit of off-loading execution onto the standby. `max_standby_archive_delay` must be kept large in this case, because delayed WAL files might already contain entries that conflict with the desired standby queries.

**Solution Implementation**:

Here's what your `postgresql.conf` should be configured to on the standby server:

```
max_standby_archive_delay = -1
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

Comment: Spot on! Hopefully this helps others; **don't forget to restart your database/server! (For example if you're running RDS)**

Comment: hot_standby_feedback is dangerous, since it forces autovacuum to wait on master and you can easily start to loose space fast on some workloads. Use it with caution.

Comment: We have a similar use-case, streaming replication between a Master and a Replica. With Replica being used heavily for read queries. We tried the mentioned three properties and are now not seeing the `conflict` errors. However, we are seeing lag go upto as high as `2000` seconds and on an avg around `500` secs. Our use-case cannot tolerate such high lag. What else can we do to bring the lag down *AND* not cause the `conflict` errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is a very good database engine in the sense that most queries won't lock the tables. Internally, it has a sort of revision system per row in your table, which means it can continue to write the WAL during your other reading transactions.

The Logs are also very resistant to delay, and unless you have a massive traffic, it will always catch up at some point.

Just make sure that you don't use Lock commands, and you'll be fine.