# OrientDB ETL - postgres - "canceling statement due to conflict with recovery"

Tags: postgresql, orientdb, orientdb-etl

I am use OrientDB OETL to extract data from postgresql. In some big query I have follow error in postgres:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
  Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

There is some way of use OETL to control this problem?

Obs: I cannot change configuration in origin postgresql database. It's not about my administration.

Comment: I think that this answer can help you (no, nothing can be done on ETL side): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592436/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery

Comment: thank you very much!