# What causes data on a read-replica to be an old_snapshot and cause conflict?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, replication

After encountering (on an RDS Postgres instance) for several times:

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed
```

I ran (on the hot standby):

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_database_conflicts;
```

And found that all the conflicts have to do with `confl_snapshot`

Which is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/monitoring-stats.html) as:

> confl_snapshot: Number of queries in this database that have been canceled due to old
>   snapshots

What might be causing this conflict (being an old snapshot)?

If it helps, here are some of the relevant settings (by running `SHOW ALL ;` on the stand by):

```
hot_standby: on
hot_standby_feedback: off
max_standby_archive_delay: 30s
max_standby_streaming_delay: 1h
name,setting
old_snapshot_threshold: -1
vacuum_defer_cleanup_age: 0
vacuum_freeze_min_age: 50000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age: 150000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age: 5000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age: 150000000
wal_level: replica
wal_receiver_status_interval: 10s
wal_receiver_timeout: 30s
wal_retrieve_retry_interval: 5s
wal_segment_size: 16MB
wal_sender_timeout: 30s
wal_writer_delay: 200ms
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592436/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery

Comment: @pifor I understand the potential solutions mentioned in your link; however, that is not exactly what I am asking. I am particularly asking about confl_snapshot and how it relates to these settings. Which is not directly answered there.

Comment: In [this documentation section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT) there is no direct reference to confl_snapshot (it only says: _The number of query cancels and the reason for them can be viewed using the pg_stat_database_conflicts system view on the standby server_) but it describes what you a experiencing (_The most common reason for conflict between standby queries and WAL replay is “early cleanup”._) and related parameters.

Comment: What version of the database are you using?

Comment: "I am particularly asking about confl_snapshot and how it relates to these settings"  confl_snapshot is a count of how many times the error like the one you first reported has occurred.  Surely you meant to ask something more interesting than that?  But I can't really figure out what it is.